# Calcular a faixa etária de idade de 10 pessoas dentro de um laço de repetição?

Tags: python, while

Abaixo está o código que estou utilizando, esta apresentando o seguinte erro:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
maycon@maycon-H14SU08:~/Documentos/Algoritimos$ python3 prova_lista.py 
  File "prova_lista.py", line 23
    elif 18 pessoas <= 65:
```

> Faça um programa que, utilizando um laço de repetição, receba a idade de 10 pessoas, calcule e mostre a quantidade de pessoas em cada faixa etária de acordo com a legenda:
>
> - Menor de idade - 0 a 17 anos
> - Jovem - 18 a 65 anos
> - Meia idade - 66 a 79 anos
> - Idoso - 80 a 99 anos
> - Idoso de vida longa - 100 ou mais

```
pessoas = [""] * 10

i = 0
soma = 0

while i < len(pessoas):
    pessoas[i] = int(input("Digite a sua idade: "))
    soma = soma + pessoas[i]
    i = i + 1

i = 0
soma = 0

while i < len(pessoas):

    pessoas = pessoas[i]
    pessoas = int(pessoas)

    soma = soma + pessoas
    i = i + 1

    if pessoas < 17:
        print("--- Menor de Idade ----")
        break

    elif 18 < pessoas <= 65:
        print("--- Jovem ---")
        break

    elif 66 < pessoas <= 79:
        print("--- Meia Idade ---")
        break

    elif 80 < pessoas <= 90:
        print("--- Idoso ---")
        break

    elif pessoas >= 100:
        print("--- Idoso de Vida Longa ---")
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você resolver esta questão basta implementar um `laço de repetição` e, `contar` a `quantidade de pessoas` que satisfazem `cada uma` das faixas etárias.

Para isso, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Capturando e tratando a quantidade de pessoas.
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Desejas inserir a idade de quantas pessoas? '))
        if n <= 0:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

cont = cont1 = cont2 = cont3 = cont4 = cont5 = 0
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    # Capturando e tratando a idade de cada pessoa.
    while True:
        try:
            idade = int(input(f'Digite a idade da {c}ª pessoa: '))
            if idade < 0:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores ou iguais a "0"!\033[m')
            else:
                break
        except:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros maiores ou iguais a "0"!\033[m')

    # Somando as idades por faixa etária.
    if 0 <= idade < 18:
        cont1 += 1
    elif 18 <= idade < 66:
        cont2 += 1
    elif 66 <= idade < 80:
        cont3 += 1
    elif 80 <= idade < 100:
        cont4 += 1
    elif idade >= 100:
        cont5 += 1

# Exibindo os resultados:
print(f'\033[32mMenor de Idade: {cont1}')
print(f'Jovem: {cont2}')
print(f'Meia Idade: {cont3}')
print(f'Idoso: {cont4}')
print(f'Idoso de Vida Longa: {cont5}')
```

Observe o funcionamento do código no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/jtsgdyse-solkarped).

Observe que este algoritmo também possui `tratamento de erros e exceções`, além de realizar a `soma da quantidade de pessoas por faixa etária`.

Answer (score 6):

faltou o operador de comparação `<` entre o número e a variável

```
elif 18 pessoas <= 65:
```

deveria ser

```
elif 18 < pessoas <= 65:
```

O mesmo para todas as outras comparações feitas.

EDIT: Acredito que você não precisa armazenar todas as pessoas... e sim o total de pessoas que está em cada faixa etária. Veja abaixo o código completo:

```
# cria variáveis para cada categoria com o valor zero:
menor = jovem = meia_idade = idoso = vida_longa = 0

# repete 10 vezes:
for n in range(10):
    idade = int(input("Digite a sua idade:"))

    # apos digitar cada idade, classifica a pessoa e incrementa a variavel certa:
    if idade <= 17:
        menor = menor + 1
    elif 17 < idade <= 65:
        jovem = jovem + 1
    elif 65 < idade <= 79:
        meia_idade = meia_idade + 1
    elif 79 < idade <= 99:
        idoso = idoso + 1
    else:
        vida_longa = vida_longa + 1

# Após processar as 10 pessoas, imprime o resultado

print("Menores de idade: ", menor)
print("Jovens: ", jovem)
print("Pessoas de meia-idade: ", meia_idade)
print("Idosos: ", idoso)
print("Idosos de vida longa: ", vida_longa)
```

Comment: Entendo, porém ainda esta apresentando o erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova_lista.py", line 20, in <module>
    if pessoas <= 17:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: Sim @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva, porém isso é outro erro diferente, causado por outro problema, desta vez de lógica - você não pode comparar listas com números.

Comment: Ok, no caso eu devo converter a lista para inteiro. O programa roda normalmente, porém só apresenta a primeira faixa etária de idade no bloco if.

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva eu acho que você não precisa de uma lista, afinal, o enunciado não mandou armazenar todas as pessoas. Você editou a pergunta mas o erro continua o antigo, edite também o erro

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva editei minha resposta e coloquei um exemplo de solução para o seu problema, espero ter ajudado, se tiver qualquer dúvida na compreensão pode abrir outra pergunta ou se for o caso, perguntar aqui

Answer (score 3):

```
pessoas = [""] * 10

i = 0
soma = 0

while i < len(pessoas):
    pessoas[i] = int(input("Digite a sua idade: "))
    soma = soma + pessoas[i]
    i = i + 1

    if pessoas <= 17:
        print("--- Menor de Idade ----")

    elif 18 < pessoas <= 65:
        print("--- Jovem ---")

    elif 66 < pessoas <= 79:
        print("--- Meia Idade ---")

    elif 80 < pessoas <= 90:
        print("--- Idoso ---")

    elif pessoas >= 100:
        print("--- Idoso de Vida Longa ---")
```

Faltou a anotação de maior ou menor antes de 'pessoas' nas suas condições :)